# Como comparar dois data frames Python

Tags: mysql, sql, python, big-data

Olá galera estou tentando automatizar um processo de carga com python trazendo dados do sql e mandando pra uma tabela do mysql e estou enfrentando alguns problemas. 
Problema: Preciso que quando tiver novos dados na minha tabela do sql meu programa verifique se esses dados estão presentes na minha tabela do mysql, caso esteja presente imprima na tela que os dados já existem e se não existirem carregar esses dados na tabela do my sql.
pensei da seguinte forma jogar os dados das duas tabelas em data frame e depois fazer estrutura de decisão nesses dois data frames, mas estou com dificuldades.
Segue o código.

> Erro- Exception has occurred: KeyError
>   'idContrato'

```
import pymysql.cursors
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Função para trazer os dados do Sql e jogar em um dataframe
def get_vendas_sqlserver():
    #Conexão com SQL Server
    connection = pyodbc.connect("DSN=SQLServer")  #autocommit=True
    try:
        # O metodo do pandas retorna o resultado do select
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM dw.dbo.vW_Vendateste123",connection,index_col=None,coerce_float=True, parse_dates= 'DataBaseContrato') 
        return df      
    finally:
        connection.close()

# jogando a função do sql dentro de uma variavel
sqlvendas = get_vendas_sqlserver()
print(sqlvendas)

# Função para trazer os dados do mysql e jogar em um dataframe
def get_vendas_mysql():
    #Conexão Mysql
    cnxmysql = pymysql.connect(host='reveka',
                                 user='carga',
                                 password='carga',
                                 db='dw')
    try:
        # O metodo do pandas retorna o resultado do select
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM ft_venda_copy", cnxmysql, index_col=None, coerce_float=True,
                               parse_dates='DataBaseContrato')
        return df
    finally:
        cnxmysql.close()

# jogando a função do mysql dentro de uma variavel
"""mysqlvendas = get_vendas_mysql()
print(mysqlvendas)"""

# Comparando os dois dataframes

df1 = get_vendas_sqlserver()
df2 = get_vendas_mysql()
#criando um dataframe vazio para guardar o resultado
df_result = pd.DataFrame()

cnx = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://teste:teste@teste/dw')
```

# Tentei usar o metodo iterrows para retornar uma tuple

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    # verifica se este registro existe no DF do MySQL
```

> Solução - Corrigido: idContrato para IdContrato

```
    if row["IdContrato"] in df2["IdContrato"]:
        print("Contrato {0} encontrada no Mysql".format(row["IdContrato"]))       
    else:
        print("Contrato {0} nao encontrada no Mysql".format(row["IdContrato"]))
        # adiciona o registro num novo DF que vai ser usado para gravar no banco adiante
        df_result.append(row)
        #carregar_resultados(df_result)
        df_result.to_sql(con=cnx, name='ft_venda_copy', if_exists='append', index=False, )
        print('dados Carregados')
```

Comment: Você está com um erro de digitação.
Ora usa IdContrato, com i maiúsculo, e ora usa idContrato. Corrija esse erro e depois volte aqui se precisar de algo mais.

Comment: Opa Rafael obrigado, vou corrigir e realizar o teste!

Comment: Obrigado Rafael era este mesmo o problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está com um erro de digitação.

Ora usa `IdContrato`, com `i` maiúsculo, e ora usa `idContrato`, com `i` minúsculo.

> por [Rafael Barros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/139386/rafael-barros)